# Convert time interval string to time in python

Tags: python, datetime

I have the following string list:

```
my_list = ['10:00AM-12:00PM','12:30PM-03:00PM']
```

And I want to convert those strings to time interval (the difference of time in format hh:mm), in this case:

```
intervals = [02:00,01:30]
```

I have tried this:

```
import time

le_vals = []
for i, val in enumerate(intervals):
   le_vals.append(val.replace('-', ' ').split(' '))

the_diff = []
for i, val in enumerate(le_vals):
   the_diff.append((time.strptime(val[1], '%I:%M%p') - time.strptime(val[0], '%I:%M%p'))
```

But I'm stuck on how the last part to get the differences on the list `the_diff`. Since I have been requested to provide a concise question, I advance my logic but please, could you help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your did a good job, but the items in the `intervals` list, are not valid in python! (you need strings?) Why don't you store them as a `timedelta` object ?

```
from datetime import datetime

my_list = ['10:00AM-12:00PM', '12:30PM-03:00PM']

res = []
for item in my_list:
    d1, d2 = item.split('-')

    d1 = datetime.strptime(d1, '%I:%M%p')
    d2 = datetime.strptime(d2, '%I:%M%p')
    res.append(d2 - d1)

print(res)
```

output :

```
[datetime.timedelta(seconds=7200), datetime.timedelta(seconds=9000)]
```

When you subtract two `datetime` objects from each other, `timedelta` object is created which has `days` and `seconds` property directly:

```
for i in res:
    print(i.days, i.seconds)
```

output:

```
0 7200
0 9000
```

If you need that string representation in question, either use `str()` on `timedelta` object(It shows seconds as well but with no zero padding hours) :

```
res = []
for item in my_list:
    d1, d2 = item.split('-')

    d1 = datetime.strptime(d1, '%I:%M%p')
    d2 = datetime.strptime(d2, '%I:%M%p')
    res.append(str(d2 - d1))  # <--------------- Here

print(res)
```

output :

```
['2:00:00', '2:30:00']
```

Or **build it yourself** to get the exact desired result, Here is a complete code:

from datetime import datetime

```
my_list = ['10:00AM-12:00PM', '12:30PM-03:00PM']

res = []
for item in my_list:
    d1, d2 = item.split('-')

    d1 = datetime.strptime(d1, '%I:%M%p')
    d2 = datetime.strptime(d2, '%I:%M%p')
    delta = d2 - d1

    m, s = divmod(delta.seconds, 60)
    h, m = divmod(m, 60)

    res.append(f'{h:02}:{m:02}')

print(res)
```

output:

```
['02:00', '02:30']
```

Comment: Thank you very much @SorousH Bakhtiary, I appreciate your time and answer, I learned a lot from your approach!, you know, I was battling against getting the difference for each tuple in the list, but your solution was clear and practical! Have a great, great day!

Comment: @Alexis Great, happy to help :)